# cant build android app on unity after installing openssl

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am getting an error from today morning. It was working fine yesterday and after that i installed openssl. After that today when I try to build on unity am getting this error.

```
Error building Player: Win32Exception: 
ApplicationName='C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javac.exe', 
CommandLine='-bootclasspath 
"F:/adt-bundle-/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030/sdk/platforms/android-19\android.jar" -d 
"C:\Users\Pillairajeshg\Documents\todaysgame\Temp\StagingArea\bin\classes" -source 1.6 -target 1.6 -encoding ascii "com\facebook\android\R.java" "my\crap\testing\R.java"', 
CurrentDirectory='C:\Users\Pillairajeshg\Documents\todaysgame\Temp\StagingArea\gen'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like when installing OpenSSL, it changed JAVA_HOME to point to a jre installation.

You should check and see if JAVA_HOME is pointing to jdk installation that has javac installed.